# Java- How can I get my TicTacToe game to check for winners properly?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm not getting any compilation errors but there has to be a logic error because my checkWinner method is not even being encountered.

this is my code for checkWinner method:

```
  public boolean checkWinner() {
  for (int i=0;i<3;i++){ 
     if ((gameBoard[i][0] == gameBoard[i][1]) && (gameBoard[i][1] == gameBoard[i][2])) { //check every row to find a match
        System.out.println(currentMark + "wins!"); 
     }
     else if ((gameBoard[0][i] == gameBoard[1][i]) && (gameBoard[1][i] == gameBoard[2][i])) { //checks every column to find a match
        System.out.println(currentMark + "wins!");
     }
  }
  if ((gameBoard[0][0] == gameBoard[1][1]) && (gameBoard[1][1] == gameBoard[2][2])) { //checks first diagonal
     System.out.println(currentMark + "wins!");
  }
  else if ((gameBoard[0][2] == gameBoard[1][1]) && (gameBoard[1][1] == gameBoard[2][0])) { //checks second diagonal
     System.out.println(currentMark + "wins!");
  }
  else 
     System.out.println("Tie!");      
  return true;
```

}

And this is my play method where I use checkWinner to check for winners every time after the user enters a move.

```
   public void letsPlay() {
  while (true) {
     displayBoard();
     gameOptions();
     int choice = input.nextInt();
     if (choice == 1) {
        if (addMove(input.nextInt(),input.nextInt())) {
           displayBoard();
           checkWinner();
           whoseTurn();

           System.exit(0);
        }
```

I'm not sure if maybe my checkWinners method should be part of my addMove method...this is addMove

```
   public boolean addMove(int row, int column) {
  boolean nonacceptable = true;
  while (nonacceptable) {
     System.out.println("Which row and column would you like to enter your mark? Enter the row and column between 0 and 2 separated by a space.");
     row = input.nextInt();
     column = input.nextInt();
     if ((row >= 0 && row <=2) && (column >= 0 && column <=2)) { //make sure user entered a number between 0 and 2
        if (gameBoard[row][column] != ' ') {
           System.out.println("Sorry, this position is not open!");
        }
        else {
           gameBoard[row][column] = currentMark;
           nonacceptable = false;
        }
     }   
     else 
        System.out.println("That position is not between 0 and 2!");
     }
     return nonacceptable;
```

}

How could I incorporate it into the addMove method or change it so it works as its own method?

Comment: in the line `if (addMove(input.nextInt(),input.nextInt()))` you are calling `input.nextInt()` twice so the user will have to enter two integers before `addMove` will get called. Is that the behavior you expect?

Comment: @neuronaut is that what is causing all the issues? what could I change that to?

Comment: I would just remove those parameters: `public boolean addMove()` and `if (addMove())`. Since that function already prompts the user and asks for input you don't need to also ask for input (without a prompt) when calling the function.

Comment: You need to check each column of each row, the check the right and left diagonals

Comment: @neuronaut okay so that fixed my issue of it taking input in twice....but it still is not recognizing winners...do you know how I can fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like when a user enters a valid answer `nonacceptable` is set to false so that the `while(nonacceptable)` loop will exit. But then you return `nonacceptable` (which is false) meaning that the check `if (addMove())` will not pass (and thus `checkWinner` isn't called). You could try moving that `if` statement down, like this:

```
addMove();
displayBoard();
if (checkWinner()) {
    System.exit(0);
}
whoseTurn();
```

However, you'll need to change `checkWinner` to return `true` only if the game has been won or tied, and return `false` otherwise.